# How to properly retrieve values/settings from a Python Tkinter radiobutton

Tags: python, tkinter

Dinking around with a Tkinter window sporting a pair of radio buttons:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Python Radio Buttons")

# Tkinter string variable
# able to store any string value
v = StringVar(window, "1")
    
def handle_click(event):
    print(v.get())
    for child in window.children.items():
        if(type(child[1]) is Radiobutton):
            print("It's a radio button")

# Dictionary to create multiple buttons
values = {"RadioButton 1" : "1",
        "RadioButton 2" : "2"}

# Loop is used to create multiple Radiobuttons
# rather than creating each button separately
for (text, value) in values.items():
    rb = Radiobutton(window, text = text, variable = v,
                value = value)
    rb.bind("<Button-1>", handle_click)
    rb.pack(side = TOP, ipady = 5)
# Infinite loop can be terminated by
# keyboard or mouse interrupt
# or by any predefined function (destroy())
mainloop()
```

Problem 1 is when I click on a radio button, the v.get() returns the value from the other radio button so the click appears to be lagging. Where am I going wrong here?

Problem 2 is I thought I might iterate through all the radio buttons to see which one was checked, but I don't see any properties (like value or checked) I can poll to get that information. If I can't do that, I am back to problem 1. Any suggestions?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I click on a radio button, the v.get() returns the value from the other radio button so the click appears to be lagging. Where am I going wrong here?

It turns out, Tkinter fires `click` event before changing value of Radiobutton's variable, so you are getting value of `StringVar` before it is changed.

> I thought I might iterate through all the radio buttons to see which one was checked, but I don't see any properties (like value or checked) I can poll to get that information.

You can retrieve Radiobutton's value by checking `value` key of Radiobutton's `config` dictionary:

```
def handle_click(event):
    print(v.get())
    for child in window.children.items():
        if(type(child[1]) is Radiobutton):
            print("It's a radio button. Value =", child[1].config("value")[-1])
```

Prints:

```
1
It's a radio button. Value = 1
It's a radio button. Value = 2
1
It's a radio button. Value = 1
It's a radio button. Value = 2
```

### But, you are doing it wrong from the beginning

To trace radiobutton's state change you should track changing of `StringVar`:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.title("Python Radio Buttons")

# Function which will be run every time StringVar is changed
def callback(var):
    print(f"Value changed to {var.get()}")

# Create variable
v = StringVar(window, "1")

# Tracing variable change state
v.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode, var=v: callback(v))

values = {"RadioButton 1" : "1",
        "RadioButton 2" : "2"}

for (text, value) in values.items():
    rb = Radiobutton(window, text = text, variable = v, value = value)
    rb.pack(side = TOP, ipady = 5)

mainloop()
```

Comment: Excellent, it never occurred to me to follow the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Changing:

```
rb.bind("<Button-1>", handle_click)
```

to

```
rb.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", handle_click)
```

will solve issue one, should in turn solve two :)

Answer (score 0):

The default handling of the selection by mouse click happens after event `<Button-1>`, that is why you get the previous value in the handler.

One option is to bind on event `<ButtonRelease-1>` instead.  But I would suggest to use `command` option of `Radiobutton()`:

```py
...
def handle_click():
    print(v.get())

...
# rather than creating each button separately
for (text, value) in values.items():
    rb = Radiobutton(window, text = text, variable = v,
                value = value, command=handle_click)  # use command option
    #rb.bind("<Button-1>", handle_click)              # instead of binding
    rb.pack(side = TOP, ipady = 5)
...
```

Note that you can use the value of `v.get()` to determine which radiobutton is selected.

Comment: Thanks. Command is the way to go, I was just curious about using the bind method.